# How to get a working clock on Debian 9? Clock is wrong by a couple minutes

Tags: debian, security, ntp, clock

How to get a working clock in Debian 9 with KDE? My clock is almost 10 minutes slow on multiple of my machines running Debian 9 with KDE and (re)setting the timezone via `tzselect` didn't work.

(I already solved this but maybe other people would like to have a working clock as well. Also I'm interested in other ways to solve this. I'm surprised this isn't taken care of by the default installation of Debian so that it works right away if you selected the right timezone during installation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Install openntpd: `sudo apt-get install openntpd`
   `ntp` did not work and I didn't try Redhat's `chrony`.
2. `sudo kate /etc/openntpd/ntpd.conf` and make sure there are 4 uncommented lines (replace `XY` with your country code):

   ```
    # Choose servers announced from Debian NTP Pool
    servers 0.XY.pool.ntp.org
    servers 1.XY.pool.ntp.org
    servers 2.XY.pool.ntp.org
    servers 3.XY.pool.ntp.org
   ```
3. If you're using iptables add these firewall rules:

   ```
    -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
    -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
    -A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 123 -j ACCEPT`
   ```

   If you're using nftables add these firewall rules(?):

   ```
    udp dport ntp counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    udp sport ntp counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept

    udp dport ntp counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    udp sport ntp counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
   ```

   The first two go into `chain INPUT` the latter two into `chain OUTPUT` of `/etc/nftables.conf`. It's better if it it's preceded by `iifname "connection name"` and `oifname "connection name"`.
4. `sudo ntpctl -s status` should return `.../20 peers valid, clock synced...`
5. (To correct the minutes: `ntpd -s`. You might have to restart the service: `sudo /etc/init.d/openntpd restart`)
6. (Make sure in `sudo kate /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf` it says `net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=0`. If it's not set change it and reboot.)
7. (If you had ntp installed before run `sudo apt-get purge ntp`. If you're using AppArmor follow [the guide in this answer at askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/929543).)